# The problem of not saving the previous value when sending it from bluetooth

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, bluetooth, c, shift-register

**Controlling Led's from Buttons and Bluetooth by same method**

**The problem now :**

the LED light up when you send an A over Bluetooth and it will turn off after 2 sec automatically without you doing anything (this is the wrong now in video).

I Want the same char when send data the led turn on and when i want closed led send same char to turn off light .

**The code: bottom this page**

**thank**

[this is the wrong now in video](https://youtu.be/EcpJeewE1AU)

[image: Photo for my Project]

```
 #define CLK 10
 #define CLKI 9
 #define LD 8
 #define SO 11
 #define SER 12

 byte ledstates;
 byte copy=0;
 unsigned long bt_leds_timestamp=0;
 byte bt_leds_activated=0;

 void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(CLK,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(CLKI,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(LD,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(SO,INPUT);
   pinMode(SER,OUTPUT); 
  }

 void loop(){
  if (Serial.available()>0){
  message();
 }
  shift_In();
  shift_out(ledstates);

  if(bt_leds_activated && millis()-bt_leds_timestamp > 2000){
  ledstates &= ~bt_leds_activated;
  shift_out(ledstates);
   bt_leds_activated = 0;
  }
 }

 void message(){
  if(Serial.available()){      // Send data only when you receive data:
  char data = Serial.read();        //Read   the incoming data & store into data
  Serial.print(data);          //Print Value inside data in Serial monitor

  switch (data){
  case 'A' :
    bt_leds_activated |= 1;
    break; 
  case 'B' :
    bt_leds_activated |= 2;
    break;
  case 'C' :
    bt_leds_activated |= 4;
    break;
  case 'D' :
    bt_leds_activated |= 8;
    break;
  case 'E' :
    bt_leds_activated |= 16;
    break;
  case 'F' :
    bt_leds_activated |= 32 ;
    break;
  case 'G' :
    bt_leds_activated |= 64;
    break;
  case 'H' :
    bt_leds_activated |= 128;
    break;
  default   : return; }    
  }
   ledstates |= bt_leds_activated;
   shift_out(ledstates);
   bt_leds_timestamp = millis();
  }

 void shift_out (byte copy){
  digitalWrite(LD, LOW);
  shiftOut(SER,CLK,MSBFIRST,copy);
  digitalWrite(LD, HIGH);
  delay(100);
 }

 void shift_In(){
  digitalWrite(CLKI,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LD,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LD,LOW);
  digitalWrite(LD,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CLK,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CLKI,LOW);
  byte buttonstates = shiftIn(SO,CLK,MSBFIRST); //read button states in a local variable
  digitalWrite(CLKI,HIGH);
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++){ // loop through all 8 bits of the buttonstates
    if(!(copy & (1<<i)) && (buttonstates & (1<<i))){ // check if old button state (in copy) is zero and new buttonstate is 1 (for the currently check bit)
        ledstates ^= 1<<i; // toggle the corresponding bit in the ledstates variable (will be shifted out later in the loop() function)
    }
  }
  copy = buttonstates;
  delay(10); // delay for debouncing
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C has an "Exclusive Or" operator which is `^`.  You can use that instead of `|` so that it toggles the bit rather than always setting it:

```
case 'A' :
    bt_leds_activated ^= 1;
    break;
```

With `^` if you OR a 0 with a 1 you get a 1. If you OR a 0 with a 0 you get a 0. If you OR a 1 with a 1 you get a 0.

That means every time you send `A` bit one of `bt_leds_activated` will invert. If it's 0 it will become 1. If it's 1 it will be come 0.

Also you seem to have two sets of states - the button states, and the bluetooth states. Instead you only want one set of states, and both the buttons and the bluetooth toggle bits in that single state set.

Because of that if *either* of the methods of turning an LED on has turned the LED on then the other method will have no chance at all of turning the LED off.

So just drop `bt_leds_activated` completely and use `ledstates`:

```
case 'A':
    ledstates ^= 1;
    break;
```

Now both the button and the character through bluetooth will toggle the LED.

Comment: No any that change for project state after edit code. the wrong still . 
hey man, please watch video to understand bug . thanks
https://youtu.be/EcpJeewE1AU

Comment: I think your problem is that you have two sets of states, when you really only want one.

Comment: What is the solution . Can you edit this bug. I think bug in this if condition

Comment: if(bt_leds_activated && millis()-bt_leds_timestamp > 2000){ ledstates &= ~bt_leds_activated; shift_out(ledstates); bt_leds_activated = 0; }

Comment: Forget `bt_leds_activated` completely. Just use `ledstates` everywhere.

Comment: Edit your answer bro, and then explain for me as example

Comment: ledstates |= bt_leds_activated; shift_out(ledstates); bt_leds_timestamp = millis();

Comment: How about these lines

Comment: I think you aren't completely clear in your own mind what you want to achieve. I have no idea what you are trying to do with those lines.

Comment: I want delay time when send char after char

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: Firstly : thank for edit my code now code run perfectly . But this code is clean code or no .and then for example when send character A by Bluetooth in real The sending process requires a time delay between the sent value and the subsequent 2nd value .

Comment: Thanks for you man on your answer for may problem